# Problems using Binary Search

Tags: java, search, binary

I am currently writing some code that is supposed to solve a sudoku puzzle for an assignment. The code I currently have written should be isolating the row and column where we need to insert a value, and then testing values 1-9 to see which ones already appear in either the row or the column. The problem is, the binary search is not detecting some numbers and I do not know why. Here is my code. All you need to no is that A.grid is an array containing the unsolved puzzle, and the set value method is one that I have written to plug a value into the array with the fromat setValue(xLocation, yLocation, value)

```
int currentVal = 0;
    int j;
    int [] currentRow = new int [9];
    int [] currentCol = new int [9];
    for (i = 0; i<9 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<9 ; j++){
            currentVal=A.grid[i][j];
            boolean keepGoing = true;
            int newVal=1;
            if (currentVal==0) {
                for( int k = 0; k < 9; k++) 
                {currentCol[k] = A.grid[k][j];
                        }
                    currentRow = A.grid[i];
                    log(Arrays.toString(currentRow));
                    log(Arrays.toString(currentCol));
                    log("");
                while (keepGoing) {
                        int indexRow=Arrays.binarySearch(currentRow, newVal);
                        int indexCol=Arrays.binarySearch(currentCol, newVal);
                        log(indexRow);
                        log(indexCol);
                        log("");
                        if (indexRow<0 && indexCol<0) {
                            keepGoing = false;
                        }
                        newVal++;

            }
            A.setValue(j, i, newVal-1);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem, but you need to make sure that your arrays are sorted if you're going to use a binary search algorithm. Otherwise, you're going to get garbage results.

That being said, why do you think you need to do a binary search on arrays with only 9 elements?  It would very likely be faster just to do the search yourself manually and forget about using a binary search at all.

```
int indexRow = -1;
for (int z = 0; z < 9; ++z)
{
    if (currentRow[z] == newVal)
    {
        indexRow = z;
        break;
    }
}

// indexRow is now the index of newVal in currentRow
```

For that matter, it would probably be clearer if that whole routine was wrapped up in a separate function:

```
int search(int[] source, int val)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < source.length; ++z)
    {
        if (source[z] == val)
        {
            // z is the position of val in the source array
            return z;
        }
    }

    // Return -1 if val is not present
    return -1;
}
```

You would then replace your binarySearch() calls with calls to search().

I hope this helps!